# Seed doesn't change for each level

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random-seed, seed

So I am making a game like snake vs blocks and I have a endless mode already but I also want a levels mode that will have like 999 levels and I want each one to have a seed for it so everyone that plays it gets the same level generation for that level, it shows up as the seed is different but doesn't change for each button I press

My first thought was oh maybe because it uses the same scene but nope I made a brand new scene and it did the exact same thing and I also just want to use a single scene instead of tons, so I am kinda stuck on what the issue is... if anyone could have that would be great if more info is needed let me know below.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SetRandomSeed : MonoBehaviour
{

public string stringSeed = "Seed string";
public bool useStringSeed;
public int seed;
public bool randomizeSeed;

void Awake()
{
    if (useStringSeed)
    {
        seed = stringSeed.GetHashCode();
    }

    if (randomizeSeed)
    {
        seed = Random.Range(0, 999);
    }

    
}


}
```

Comment: You really need to provide a [mcve]. The code you've presented is not valid code. Real code that we can test is paramount.

Comment: note that `Random.Range(0, 999)` also relies on a generator and will produce the same seed `x` if itself is set to the same seed `y`. +1 @Enigmativity

Comment: @DanielTuzes as far as I understand [`Random`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.InitState.html) is initialized on app start with `(int)DateTime.Now.Ticks` so pretty unlikely that it has the same seed twice ;)

Comment: @OP if you just want a seed you could use that yourself `(int)DateTime.Now.Ticks`

Comment: @derHugo - Unity uses a completely different `Random` class than `System.Random`. It uses a "high-entropy seed from the operating system" when it is initialized. In this case, however, I don't think the OP is talking about the seed used for the PRNG. It sounds like code he is creating for his app level generation. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.html

Comment: @Enigmativity seemingly you didn't even click on my link ^^ otherwise you would see it refers to the very same `UnityEngine.Random.InitState` ;) they don't really state how it is initialized by default I just guessed they use the system ticks as well because they mention it in the `InitState` doc ... And I know, that's why I said actually OP doesn't even need to use Random at all .. he could also simply use the system ticks itself as seed for the level generation .. we can't know without more context of course ;)

Comment: @derHugo - I don't know how they initialize it either, but they say "high entropy" - so that rules out `Ticks`.